# Using stream_with_context as async

Tags: python, flask, pyrogram

I want to stream a file in telegram using pyrogram, but I can't do it because stream_with_context is not working asynchronously, what can I do?

How can I send a file (bytes) to the user asynchronously via flask? No matter how hard I searched, I could not find the answer to this question, there are always answers for synchronous flasks on the internet.

If I try to use flask synchronously, this time the pyrogram with telegram api starts to cause problems because this api is mainly made for async

```
from flask import Response

from flask import Flask, send_file
from flask import stream_with_context

app = Flask(__name__)


import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client

api_id = 000
api_hash = ""

tg = Client("aaa", api_id, api_hash)

@app.route('/bigfile')
async def bigfile():
    msg = await tg.get_messages(0674564523, 4564535254)

    async def gnn():
        async for chunk in tg.stream_media(msg):
            chnk = io.BytesIO(chunk)
            yield chnk

    return Response(
        stream_with_context(await gnn()),
        headers={
            'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename=asdfasdf.pdf'
        }
    )

import threading


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=app.run, daemon=True).start()
    tg.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can iterate an async iterator manually by applying some glue code:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595496/8981929)

```
def iter_over_async(ait, loop):
    ait = ait.__aiter__()
    async def get_next():
        try: obj = await ait.__anext__(); return False, obj
        except StopAsyncIteration: return True, None
    while True:
        done, obj = loop.run_until_complete(get_next())
        if done: break
        yield obj
```

You can use this to convert an async generator to synchronous in flask.stream_with_context:

```
async def async_gen():
    for i in range(5):
        yield f"{i}\n"
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

@app.route("/app/async")
def get_data():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    iter = iter_over_async(async_gen(), loop)
    ctx = flask.stream_with_context(iter)
    response = flask.Response(ctx, content_type='application/json')
    response.headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'
    response.headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'
    return response
```