# How to yield into asyncio.run?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I know I'm missing something basic here.

**Prerequisite**: I'm not allowed to edit `'__main__'`.

Given that prerequisite, how can I print `x` as soon as `fun()` returns something ? I know I can use `asynio.gather`, but that would mean waiting for everything to complete.

```
import asyncio


async def fun(n):
    for i in range(n):
        await asyncio.sleep(i*.1)
        yield i


def main(n):
    yield from asyncio.run(fun(n))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 5
    for x in main(n):
        print(x)
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what you need and why the code you've provided doesn't work as you want it to?

Comment: `asyncio.run` is sync function, you can't 'yield from' it.

Comment: I just want to print/use the output from `fun()` in `__main__` as soon as it yields an item.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595496/1600898) help? It should [apply to your case.](https://pastebin.com/PJdZdxeS)